# Move calendar entry in Microsoft Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, lotus-notes

How can I move calendar entry from one hour slot (say, 10am to 11am) to another (1pm - 2pm) using Mouse without loosing hour slot? I am in the `Scheduling Assistant` feature in the Outlook.

[image]

It is frustrating to loose one hour slot when I am rescheduling the meeting. (We recently moved from IBM Lotus Notes to Outlook, and Lotus Notes had this feature to easily move the meeting slots in the calendar).

This animation describes my frustration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Schedule View (not Scheduling Assistant). Switch to Schedule View via View tab > Arrangement group > Schedule View:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Steve Fan. It is similar to what I am looking for. I wish they had this view with weekly calendar. So, that it is easy to reschedule to next day, if need be. Also, is it possible to shrink the hourly columns? So, that it can show more days?

Comment: @Cricrazy You can do the same thing in Work Week or Week view of your calendar. The hourly column can be changed via the 'Time Scale' option, but the maximum time scale is 60 minutes.